# Laravel download file from localhost

Tags: laravel

my laravel web application is into this folder :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp
```

and when I'm uploading file. file is storing into this folder:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\public_html\uploads\lesson_files
```

for example:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\public_html\uploads\lesson_files\123.mp3
```

now when i try to download file from the url i get error, for example:

```
php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.104

http://192.168.1.104:8000/uploads/lesson_files/123.mp3
```

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: did you rename `public` to `public_html`?

Comment: @Saly3301 no, i have both of those folders

Comment: @Saly3301 i moved `uploads` folder to `public` folder and solved